# transparency issue

Tags: texturing, transparency

im trying to make this show up as it does on the texture, but it isnt working as intended
[[image: having trouble with nodes here]
[[image: by technicality its transparent but it isnt showing the depth of it if that makes sense- dont know how to fix it]

im just not entirely certain what to do to fix it, if any suggestions or help could be offered, that would be much appreciated

Comment: Plug the texture node's alpha output into the alpha input on the principled.  In properties/material/settings, change blend mode to alpha hashed.  If you don't see blend mode, change to Eevee render to see it.  (You're in material preview, which uses Eevee renderer.)

Comment: i didnt see any sort of change in it, its still the exact same as before

Comment: Just to correct the top comment - you appear to be in _Solid Preview_ mode (not material preview). First thing I would suggest is switching to one of the "rendered"  (shaded) modes (either material preview or rendered preview). Press Z in the 3D viewport and select either one from the pie menu.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett once i do that, what do you suggest i do? or... would that fix the issue entirely?

Comment: I think that solid preview mode (the one you are in) uses a basic renderer that doesn't include transparency in its calculations - the other two modes use renderers that definitely do transparency (though you must enable it by changing the material's blend mode away from _opaque_ if using material preview, or eevee for rendering).